# Can't add a my own background for to the footer of Twenty Eleven Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I'd been trying to do some minor edits to the wordpress theme Twenty Eleven but it looks like little bit tricky.

What I was trying to do is changing the background of the footer. I had been editing footer.php directly. I was able to change the background color of it. But i failed when adding an image as a background.

Here is my code after editing... (I added red as the background color)

```
<footer style = "background: red; width: 100%;"  id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
```

This code works fine.. but look at the following...

```
<footer style = "background:url('images/body.jpg'); width: 100%;"  id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
```

It doesn't work! I'm so confused...

Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: The CSS of the theme's footer? Please

Comment: If red works, then it means that images/body.jpg hasn't been found. Check the link, and remember : it's relative to the page !

Comment: The path in wordpress usually start from the /wp-content/ directory

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#colophon{
  background-image: url('yourimageurl');
}
```

in style.css